# Access Outlook Android app events locally from custom app

Tags: android, outlook, android-contentprovider, activesync

My intent is to have ability to see newly added events to Outlook android app in aggregator application without network connection.

What I tried:

1) **ActiveSync** does not sync the calendars/events locally (considering the source code), and it does not access the content providers of local Outlook app directly, instead it manages only the default calendar providers on android.

2) **Query content providers** - does not work, because all the providers of Outlook app have `android:exported="false"`

Maybe there is the Android Guru, who can suggest the third option?

Comment: I'd love to know this too, so many users are asking how they can get their outlook events in my calendar app